# Nesting boxes from the outside in

Tags: boxes, alignment, nesting

Array programming languages have the concept of boxing. J is such a language. Boxes can contain anything, nothing included. Most of all, because of array languages' design, boxing happens from the outside inwards, and is also visually presented that way, as can be seen in the environment provided by `fancyvbr`, wherein lays the result from jconsole  from an input of `<(<1),<<2`.

For non-nested examples, e.g. list of empty and 1, `\fbox{}` suffices.

However, for a box of (a box with 1) and (a box with (a box with 2)), the two boxes' frames at level 1 do not align because they are constructed from the inside out, that is, they grow instead of shrink.

I sought for similar quandries in the TeX SE, I sought boxing and nesting packages in CTAN, but found nothing relevant. Using `\hline`s and nested `\tabular` would have worked were it not for no explicit `\vspace{...}`. I may missing something very simple, but I expect a massive block of TiKZ code, nothing simple.

Here is my practice sheet, that is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype,calc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.20pt}
\setlength{\dashlength}{3pt}
\setlength{\hangindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \newlength{\myht}   \settoheight{\myht}{0}
  \newlength{\mydp}   \settodepth{\mydp}{0}
  \newlength{\mylen}  \setlength{\mylen}{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\myht-\mydp-1.1pt\relax}
  \def\ebox{\fbox{\hbox to 0.25ex{\vbox to \mylen{}}}}
}
\usepackage[raster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\ebox\fbox{\fbox{1}}}

\fbox{\fbox{1}\fbox{\fbox{2}}}

\fbox{ \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline 1 & \fbox{ \hbox to 0.2ex {\vbox to 5ex{}}2 }\\ \hline\end{tabular} }
\begin{Verbatim}
┌───────┐
│┌─┬───┐│
││1│┌─┐││
││ ││2│││
││ │└─┘││
│└─┴───┘│
└───────┘
\end{Verbatim}

{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1ex}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
1 & \fbox{2} \\
\hline\end{tabular}
}

\fbox{\fbox{\ebox}\fbox{1 2}}\\
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{2cm}\begin{tcbitemize}[size=fbox,sharp corners,colframe=black,colback=white,raster equal height,raster force size=false,raster equal skip=0pt,raster column skip=2mm]%
\tcbitem 1 2 3%
\tcbitem 1 2%
\end{tcbitemize}\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

Which compiles to
[image]

EDIT: I want to reproduce the Verbatim example. It doesn't matter whether boxes' contents are vertically centered, only that boxes at the same level have frames at the same baseline, that is, their depths and heights are the same.

Comment: Your question is rather hard to follow. Perhaps it would be easier if we could see the MWE output but the supplied code gives `! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.4   \DefineShortVerb{\Ь}`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "do not align?"  All boxes, whether next to each other or nested, share the same baseline.  Tabular and minipage have multiple baselines inside and have to choose one.  See also \vbox, \vcenter and \vtop.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want that is [not this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLGDI.png)  from `\fbox{\fbox{ 1 \fbox{ 2 }}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hey, Dave, long time no see, We talked on the chat long ago, I've lost account details. Anyway, the fboxed example is impossible in most-to-all array languages because at the same level you have both a number and a box (different data types)

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'll check them vcenter and vtop in the texbook. I don't know what multiple baselines is supposed to mean.
By 'align' I mean their outtermost frames do not align, at least in the pdf I'm producing with tectonic.

Comment: sorry It is still very hard to guess what you are asking. You have edited the example but it is still unusable `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \dashlength` Please test the example does demonstrate the issue you are having.

Comment: There is a visual example of what is desired. There is textual description of what is desired. Commenting out an obviously unused, undeclared length is so far out of reach, it reminds me why I strayed from this toxic hellhole. Nobody helps, and people solve their own problems usually.

Comment: you may find that not providing untested broken examples and not being rude to people offering to help makes it more likely you get answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newlength\maxht
\newlength\maxdp
\newcommand\cbox[1]{%
  \readlist*\mylist{#1}%
  \maxht=0pt
  \maxdp=0pt
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\z}%
    \ifdim\ht0>\maxht\relax\maxht=\ht0\fi
    \ifdim\dp0>\maxdp\relax\maxdp=\dp0\fi
  }
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
    \fbox{\z\rule[-\maxdp]{0pt}{\dimexpr\maxdp+\maxht}}%
    \kern-\fboxrule
  } 
}
\parskip1em
\begin{document}

\cbox{1,2}

\cbox{1,\cbox{2}}

\cbox{\cbox{1,\cbox{2}}}

\cbox{\cbox{\cbox{\cbox{1,2},3,4}, 5}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a great answer, but fiddling with the frame width and the separation lengths an invisible box could be salable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0pt}
\newcommand{\FBOX}[1]{{\fbox{\setlength{\fboxsep}{\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}\fbox{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\nbox}[1]{{\fbox{\setlength{\fboxsep}{\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}#1}}}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\fbox{1}\fbox{\fbox{2}}}

\nbox{\fbox{1}}\fbox{\fbox{2}}

\FBOX{1}\fbox{\fbox{2}}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Increasing the `fboxsep` by the to-be-gone `fboxrule` helps alleviate the discrepancy, but there persists a visible distance between neighboring boxes, something miniscule, like 1 pixel.

Comment: Please embed and highlight somehow your solution in the code, which is complete in the senses of: "can be copied and compiled". Wrt the question including a screenshot may be helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to match the height, width or both of a savebox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip=1ex

\newcommand{\matchbox}[2]% #1 = box register, #2 = contents
  {\makebox[\wd#1]{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht#1][\dp#1]{#2}}}
  
\begin{document}
\sbox0{\fbox{A}}%
\fbox{\usebox0}\fbox{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht0][\dp0]{B}}

\fbox{\usebox0}\fbox{\makebox[\wd0]{B}}

\fbox{\usebox0}\fbox{\matchbox{0}{B}}

\sbox1{\fbox{\usebox0}\fbox{\matchbox{0}{B}}}%
\sbox2{\fbox{\usebox1}\fbox{\matchbox{1}{C}}}%
\fbox{\usebox2}\fbox{\matchbox{2}{D}}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]